# How to hang this pendant light

Tags: electrical, lighting, uk

This is the UK. We bought a pendant light which says "hang by the loop". Are you supposed to put a hook in the ceiling to hang it from? Never seen one like that before.

[image: Pendant Light base]

Comment: It looks like that loop is welded on, so should be quite strong.  Would use a hook/chain about the same thickest and screw/mount into a ceiling joist.

Comment: Well apparently they make a a hook for this: https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/COFHP.html

Comment: Make an answer out of that, @Marty. Self-answered questions are perfectly acceptable around here.

Comment: I believe that you received half a fixture. There's generally a [cap and loop in the same finish](http://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/6462ef42-062c-4acb-8c6c-81e8b19c98cc/10953606.jpg) that mounts to the box. What you posted below wouldn't be attractive at all and wouldn't adequately (or legally) close a box.

Comment: Care to share the exact brand/model (and maybe even a link) to the fixture. It does seem as though parts may be missing.

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't include the hook in the package - cheapskates ;) I have two chandeliers with tops like this, both included the hook. [B&Q, no idea the manufacturer].

Comment: I ended up getting a hanger from TCL electric. Everything came with the light that should have come. The picture might be missing a few bits but it's all there.
Not where we bought from but this is the lamp
https://www.lampgallerian.se/lampor/taklampor/hamilton-taklampa

Comment: Actual store we bought it from https://www.lighting-direct.co.uk/edit-hamilton-glass-ceiling-pendant-light-clear.html

Answer (score 4):

Well apparently they make [a hook](https://tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/COFHP.html) for this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves your problem. You still need a UL-listed box covering.

Comment: Maybe, @isherwood, this hook attaches to the box in the ceiling and there's something in the lamp kit that we're not seeing that would hold that shroud up to the ceiling, completing the enclosure?

Comment: The cup part the OP is holding in their photo slides up the fixture to cover the hook after install. There should be a plastic grub screw [out of shot] at the bottom to hold it in place.

Comment: @isherwood * CA rated. I assume that’s what the black shroud does? Covers the wire connection, equivalent to how this works: https://www.diy.com/departments/bg-white-e14-pendant-set/5050765170949_BQ.prd

Comment: The hook has worked well. Just screwed it directly into the lath and plaster and it's holding well. The light isn't very heavy so no issues with that.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this:
[image]

You thread the power cord through the chain.

Comment: Agreed, except... The wires from the fixture itself are _very_ short. That means the connections would need to sit inside the shroud just below the loop. I doubt that would meet code in the US or the UK. In general, though, this is the way something like this would be hung.

Comment: The pendant itself is complete as it is - it's just missing the hook that fastens to the ceiling. It's a common chandelier type in the UK.

Comment: As @Tetsujin said I got everything that was expected. I just have never installed something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install a hook in the ceiling to hang the pendant light. You can ask your supplier if they include the hanging kit with the light together.

Note: be sure the hook can support 2 times the weight of the light.

Comment: If the hook is supplied with the fixture, would it not be safe to presume it's designed to support the weight of said fixture? Also, where does the "2x" suggestion come from? Is that code in the UK?

Comment: 2 times the weight of the light does not seem enough to swing from it.

Comment: If the hook is supplied with the fixture together, then it's designed to support the weight of the fixture. It's strong enough and safe.